# How to start the camera directly from a web page in android

Tags: android, web-applications, mobile-website

Im trying to make a webapp for Android in which i can upload pictures.
I have a web page with a fileupload field. When I push the button I can choose which app i would like to use to choose the file to upload. Is it posible (and how) to have the camera app in this list? Or do I maybe need a special app for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code to get access to the new camera api's in android 3+ and iOS 6.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

This will allow you to take a new picture or select one from the device library and then upload it to a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/). The included [example](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/tree/master/example) includes the camera. The full set of PhoneGap camera API's is documented [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera).

Comment: PhoneGap is used to build your own apps, it doesn't work directly from a webapp as the OP described.  Is there another way to implement what PhoneGap does from a webapp (ie javascript)?