# Can you launch the native Camera App from an Html 5 Web App?

Tags: android, web-applications, android-camera

I have a mobile website that allows users to upload photos using the file input type (Browse button).  If possible, I would like to launch the Camera App of an Android device on click of the Browse button or any other HTML button.  Is this possible?

I read this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296644/how-to-start-the-camera-directly-from-a-web-page-in-android) but in their example they are asking how to register the Camera App as Intent Receiver for uploading images. Similar to that, I just want to launch the Camera App in the same way the Android browser picks up on Phone Number and Addresses.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Android 3.0 Honeycomb added [Device API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928) [support](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/android-3-0-honeycomb-is-first-to-implement-the-device-api). 
Google I/O [2011 presentation](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/events/io/2011/static/presofiles/retomeier_html5_versus_android.pdf) shows an example on slide 30:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

It also points to a [test site](http://html5photos.appspot.com) that not surprisingly does not do much on my Froyo phone.

*Anybody* with a tablet tried it and can **tell us** what it does and does not do?

4.0 Icecream Sandwich was [announced](http://uk.ibtimes.com/articles/237837/20111026/motorola-devices-set-to-receive-android-ice-cream-sandwich-update-by-christmas-razr-defy.htm). Code drop may not happen [for several months](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/100285-android-ice-cream-sandwich-this-is-not-the-treat-you-are-looking-for) or [longer](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/10/20/google_ice_cream_sandwich_freedom) and actual devices may show in the market around Christmas. As to Icecream on current generation of Froyo / Gingerbread phones, official ODM/carrier 4.0 releases will never happen? I'd love to be proved wrong on this. Any word from custom ROMs community?

Comment: Just tried it on my Honeycomb tablet. When you press the button, the camera application starts, allowing you to take a picture. An "OK" button appears once the picture is taken, and if you press it, you'll get back to the website and the photo appears in the black rectangle.

Comment: @Michell Pretty cool!
A couple of other defined selectors are
accept="video/*;capture=camcorder"
accept="audio/*;capture=microphone"
W3C spec defaults to capture=filesystem
Wanna try those as well, please?

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because it seems to work on 3+, but it does not work as expected on 2.3.  At least not the ROM I am using. Thanks @WalterKarshat

Comment: On Android 4.3, this let me select the camera or other capture options, but only user2777963's answer actually brought me directly to the camera app.

Comment: @gatoatigrado which answer allowed you open camera app directly. my web app in android also opens image chooser with all gallery options along with camera. I just need to open direct camera in android.

Answer (score 28):

I tried this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

from here: https://coderwall.com/p/epwmoa

With my Galaxy S2 phone (on Chrome).

It's working and open directly the camera.

Comment: I think so but I didn't try recently. Can you try with this link ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNBMNe

Comment: Tested it with android 10 and it did the job!

Answer (score 2):

if someone need, i'm using the confirmed answer on asp.net.
i added to asp.net control the attributes `accept="image/*" capture="camera"`

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="bt_AttUp" runat="server" onClick="bt_AttUp_Click" />
```

and on .net server side

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("PathDestination")
```