# Access mobile device camera from a grails application using jquery mobile

Tags: iphone, flash, grails, jquery-mobile, webcam

I have a grails application using jquery mobile. I am hoping to find some way to access the camera on the devices. I thought about using flash to grab the webcam but that obviously wont work on Apple devices.

Does anyone know of a way to do it and keep it all browser based? I am hoping that there is a plugin somewhere or maybe html5 has some magic in there that supports it.

Comment: possible duplicate post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676036/can-you-launch-the-native-camera-app-from-an-html-5-web-app

Answer (score 0):

I have researched this quite a bit (although about six months ago) and there is no API in the Mobile Safari browser for accessing a device's camera.

You have to have a native application for this type of functionality. For instance PhoneGap lets you use a device's camera: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture