# Capture image via Android camera from browser using PHP

Tags: php, android

Is it possible to capture an image using Android camera via browser with PHP or another Library for PHP? I know it can be done by phone gap, but I'm trying to do it with PHP. Because my other Project using PHP too.

Can Anyone help me to find the solution?

Comment: why did you put all caps in your title? There is no need to shout.

Comment: I don't think PHP can do that lol...

Comment: @Tim, yeah thats my mistake, anything else?

Answer (score 7):

I found that it's possible for Android 3.0+ devices. It launches the camera, and when the picture is taken returns the the page.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811843/1536522

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Comment: I have been reading Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7811843/1536522 and trying too your solution, but the camera still can't automaticly start after i click the upload button. the html 5 :<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"> is not work on my gingerbrad tablet camera. is there any solution?

Comment: The article mentions that your device needs to run Honeycomb or better (3.0+). Gingerbread is 2.3 and will not work unfortunately. I tested on my Jelly Bean phone (4.1) and it opens the camera when I click "Browse".

Comment: I use something like CloudCam which includes it's own simple http server then you just link to the second url for the cloudcam server