# Accessing ONLY the Camera on Android/iOS via website

Tags: android, ios, camera, web

I am creating a website that requires users to upload pictures captured by their cameras and to restrict them of uploading existing images. Would this be possible? If not what are the alternatives? With much appreciation! Thanks!

I have found that it's possible to call the camera input function from a website but it allows the option of choosing from existing photos
[Can you launch the native Camera App from an Html 5 Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676036/can-you-launch-the-native-camera-app-from-an-html-5-web-app)