# How to upload image from android camera to webserver (NOT IN APP)

Tags: php, android, html, android-camera

Can i turn on camera on android device to take and send picture to my webserver when user clicked on input type="file" on mobile version of my website in phone web browser?

Now it starts phone file manager to select image file already stored on sd-card or phone memory.

Can i use phone camera in that case or i strictly need to make app?

Comment: You want to allow your web application to access the android device's camera? Is that what you trying to do?

Comment: Yes! That i want to do! But it isn't android app. It's just a mobile version of my website.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296644/how-to-start-the-camera-directly-from-a-web-page-in-android

Comment: I don't think this is possible using a server-side scripting. server-side scripting does not have access to client's hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [karmafunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736639/karmafunk) for this solution!

Here is the code to get access to the new camera api's in android 3+ and iOS 6.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

This will allow you to take a new picture or select one from the device library and then upload it to a web app.

Comment: The latest draft of the media capture specification changed the `capture` attribute to a boolean flag, so it does not need a value: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/