# can I get images from my Android/iPhone with Jquery or Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can I get images from my `Android/iPhone` with `Jquery` or `Jquery Mobile`?

Example:

I just took a photo with my `Android`, can I use it in my `WebApp`?

Comment: Hi thormayer, check this if useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296644/how-to-start-the-camera-directly-from-a-web-page-in-android

Comment: use phonegap/cordova.